What is the science behind why when displacement is increased, so will the final velocity?
I'm writing a paper and need to write a hypothesis. I did an experiment using a weighted cart with a string and falling mass, and also a pulley. This was completed on a flat table onto the floor. In the experiment I changed the displacement throughout, as my independent variable. I was measuring final velocity. I need to write a hypothesis but am struggling. Can anyone explain the science behind why when the displacement is increased, the final velocity will also increase in a simple way?

Your experimental set up isn't very clear to me right now. Could you please update your question with a better description and perhaps a sketch?

An object is accelerating while it is falling. That means velocity is increasing with time. Of course, the higher an object is (you call it "displacement"), the longer it will accelerate (under earth's gravitational field) meaning it will have a greater final velocity.

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. You want to explain why more displacement means more kinetic energy. Do you know how work relates to force?

could you add a sketch of the experimental setup?


Can anyone explain the science behind why when the displacement is increased, the final velocity will also increase in a simple way?

I am going to assume that when you say "final velocity" you mean the velocity of the cart just before it reaches the pulley.
The falling mass and pulley system exerts a constant horizontal force on the cart. If the cart starts further back from the pulley, this force acts on the cart for a longer time, and so the final velocity of the cart increases.
An alternative argument that reaches the same conclusion is to say that as the falling mass falls it loses potential energy. Some of this potential energy will be lost to the environment as heat due to friction, but if frictional losses are small then most of the potential energy goes into increasing the kinetic energy of the cart.  The further the mass falls, the more potential energy it loses, and so the greater the kinetic energy (and hence velocity) of the cart.

This one nicely explains the science behind the behavior of falling bodies.

The hypothesis should be along the lines:
A falling object increases its velocity by certain amount, each unit of time. So, the higher I place the object (what I call "displacement"), the more the time it will spend falling and so the higher its final velocity will be.

Agreed, this would make a very good hypothesis for an experimental paper.
